# Passing 20+ arguments into a function

Tags: php

I'm writing several functions that pass arguments into the function, but many of them require 20-30 arguments to be passed to the function. For the purposes of this example, i'm only including the relevant portions of code in the function below.

For example, I want to pass arguments into a function like this:

```
function shortexample($id, $name, $pass) {
    $body = array(
        'username' => "$name",
        'password' => "$pass",
        'campaign_id' => $id
    );
}
```

Where I anticipate problems is passing many (20-50) variables into the function, rather than just 3 above, it seems very inefficient to pass that many arguments, and perhaps there might even be a memory issue if I pass too many of them.

**So my actual question is what is the best method to efficiently pass a ridiculous amount of arguments into a PHP function.**

I don't want to ask you guys to post finished code, although I welcome any snippets you could provide, but really I just want to know what you guys think the best practice would be to pass an extreme number of arguments into a function.

**Update/Clarification:**
*To be more specific, the purpose for needing so many arguments, is because the values are required for an API request. Rather than writing the same code over and over, I am writing a function that I can call to make the API request as needed, but I need to pass the arguments/variables into the function, and then place them into the array, which is then sent with the API request. All of the values are very small strings, or numerical values.*

Comment: Passing 20 arguments will surely not "cause a memory issue". It's very bad style, though. Consider passing an (associative) array instead.

Comment: Hard to say for you specific case, but in general, it's a sign of bad design if you need so many parameters. Maybe there's a different structure. Often, this problem can be solved by using a pattern like the builder pattern, but there is not enough information to tell whether that's the case here.

Comment: @Mastrianni See Variadic Functions in my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the best way to get complex values ​​either through dependency injection, using a more advanced programming model, especially object-oriented

```
function shortexample(\stdClass $args) {
    $body = array(
        'username' => $args->username,
        'password' => $args->pass,
        'campaign_id' => $args->id,
    );
}
```

You should improve the definition of objects that will be received, using interfaces

```
//....
interface shortExampleInterface {
    public function getUsername();
    public function getPass();
    public function getId();
}



function shortexample(\shortExampleInterface $args) {
    $body = array(
        'username' => $args->getUsername(),
        'password' => $args->getPass(),
        'campaign_id' => $args->getId(),
    );
}
```

But I see that as the context may actually require very parameters, it is worth trying the new feature of PHP 5.6:

**Variadic Functions**

This feature allows you to capture a variable number of arguments to a function, combined with "normal" arguments passed in if you like. It's easiest to see with an example:

```
function concatenate($transform, ...$strings) {
    $string = '';
    foreach($strings as $piece) {
        $string .= $piece;
    }
    return($transform($string));
}

echo concatenate("strtoupper", "I'd ", "like ",
    4 + 2, " apples");
```

The parameters list in the function declaration has the ... operator in it, and it basically means " ... and everything else should go into `$strings`". You can pass 2 or more arguments into this function and the second and subsequent ones will be added to the `$strings` array, ready to be used.

Example 2:

```
function f($req, $opt = null, ...$params) {
    // $params is an array containing the remaining arguments.
    printf('$req: %d; $opt: %d; number of params: %d'."\n",
           $req, $opt, count($params));
}

f(1);
f(1, 2);
f(1, 2, 3);
f(1, 2, 3, 4);
f(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Comment: I think this answer is a too generic answer for a too generic question. Not my downvote, though. I do agree with your line of thinking. -edit- I see the code addition now, and I don't really agree with that. stdClass doesn't allow for type checking. I would rather use a specific class or interface.

Comment: I was still writing :D

Comment: Cheerio! That's better. ;)

Comment: Check Variadic Functions on PHP 5.6 New features http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php

Answer (score 1):

Pre PHP 5.6 you can use `func_get_args()` to get an array of all arguments passed. You can also use `call_user_func_array()` to pass unpack an array of arguments to be passed to a function.

Answer (score 0):

Pass an Associative array that will be the function list. Each key will be the name of the argument ($id, $name $etc) and the value will be the value you'd like passed for that argument.